# Batch Insert into table based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table "Affiliations". I want to insert new record for each "field1" in Affiliations where IndividualId = 'value'.

For records with an IndividualId = '69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' and field1 values are:
'7fb850d0-a226-4163-b7df-c19c1f2f7179'
, '600345d2-6f62-4211-9e68-bd2a19deaa83'
, '6b6ce4a6-d4a1-4fe9-affa-2f1e1705aead'
, 'a06851e6-5b5d-4129-a353-f333c0488ff4'
, '66bcf92d-6dd0-4ed2-abd4-3fbacbdf1aeb'
, '4aae5af8-ae8b-4dba-bd0c-43942b64319e'
, '548c9767-7b84-423b-a73f-e924d0fc6bb0'

I would expect 6 new records would be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into affiliations (individualid, field1)
values 
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , '7fb850d0-a226-4163-b7df-c19c1f2f7179'),
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , '600345d2-6f62-4211-9e68-bd2a19deaa83'),
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , '6b6ce4a6-d4a1-4fe9-affa-2f1e1705aead'),
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , 'a06851e6-5b5d-4129-a353-f333c0488ff4'),
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , '66bcf92d-6dd0-4ed2-abd4-3fbacbdf1aeb'),
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , '4aae5af8-ae8b-4dba-bd0c-43942b64319e'),
(69f7a833-eece-43b7-aa333f5aede6593e' , '548c9767-7b84-423b-a73f-e924d0fc6bb0');
```

You listed 7 values so this will create 7 new rows.

Answer (score 0):

- You write your basic SELECT statement.
- Adjust your SELECT statement to hold all the values you wanna insert into your table
- Throw INSERT INTO above it.

In pseudocode:

```sql
INSERT INTO myDestinationTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2,
  col3
FROM mySourceTable 
WHERE IndividualId = 'that guid up there'
  AND field1 IN (that gnarly list you dumped us)
```

This site seems like a good [intro to inserts](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-insert-statement/).